# slide toogle element, which was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple html code:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <button onclick="test()">Button</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <button onclick="test()">Button</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <button onclick="test()">Button</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and my javascript function:

```
function test() {
    // do something
}
```

Now, if I clicked on a button I would like to remove the whole

element of the button, which was clicked. Can you show me how? :/

With "remove" I mean

```
$(selector).toggle( "slide" );
```

Comment: if you click on first button you want to remove button element or full li tag ?

Answer (score 0):

First, [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - they're inelegant, tedious to work with, and have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays. Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` or jQuery instead.

Iterate over all the buttons and add a listener to each. When clicked, navigate to the button's parent and call `.toggle('slide')` on it:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggle( "slide" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
      <button>Button</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <button>Button</button>
   </li>
   <li>
      <button>Button</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Instead, you can easily attach an event handler to all buttons in jQuery like:

```js
$('ul button').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').toggle( "slide" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><button>Button 1</button></li>
   <li><button>Button 2</button></li>
   <li><button>Button 3</button></li>
</ul>
```

---

In case, you still want to use inline event handlers then you can simply pass `this` inside the handler like:

```
<button onclick="test(this)">Button</button>
```

and update your javascript function like:

```
function test(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('li').toggle("slide");
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function test(obj) {
  $(obj).closest('li').toggle("slide");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><button onclick="test(this)">Button 1</button></li>
  <li><button onclick="test(this)">Button 2</button></li>
  <li><button onclick="test(this)">Button 3</button></li>
</ul>
```